# .NET Web Forms Dynamic Vanity URL (not mvc)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create an *.aspx web form that will resolve to a vanityURL.

Example:

www.mydomain.com/EventName1

www.mydomain.com/OtherEventName2

Where both EventName1 and OtherEventName2 load the same Event.aspx web form and that Event.aspx web form will parse the URL and load the relevant content from the associated database.

The visitor could browse to www.mydomain.com/EventName1 and they would be presented with the database content associated with that vanity URL EventName1.

I want all of this to be **dynamic**.

Example database schema: EventID | Title | Description | VanityURL

**How do I get Event.aspx to respond for those dynamic Vanity URLs?**

Comment: You'll want to look into routing or FriendlyUrls.

Answer (score 1):

This microsoft msdn took me through it step by step. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx